# Javafx setOnMouseClicked not working at all - ImageView - nothing

Tags: javafx, imageview, eventhandler, gridpane

I'm trying to write a simple puzzle game in JavaFX. I want the image to be cut int pieces and then I would like to swap them when I click on them. The problem is the solution I had used to work when everything was in Main (as I created another scene in main, then switched to it). I tried to make the code a bit cleaner, so I created another FXML file and a controller to it. I've also previously used buttons instead of ImageViewers. Could this be the problem?

I can see that some people say there is no OnAction property in ImageViewer. But some got it working. Should I just give up and use buttons?

```
public class Grid  implements Initializable{


    public Image done;
    public BufferedImage orgin;
    public BufferedImage bwhite;
    public Image iwhite;
    public Image[][] arr =new Image[6][6];
    public ImageView [][]iv = new ImageView[6][6];

    public GridPane gridPane;
    public ImageView tmp1=new ImageView(iwhite);
    public ImageView special= tmp1;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane Magic;

    private void switcher()
    {
        gridPane.getChildren().forEach(button-> button.setOnMouseClicked(
                event -> {
                    swap(button, special);
                    System.out.println("sth");

                }
        ));
    }

    public static void swap(Node n1, Node n2) {
        Integer temp = GridPane.getRowIndex(n1);
        GridPane.setRowIndex(n1, GridPane.getRowIndex(n2));
        GridPane.setRowIndex(n2, temp);

        temp = GridPane.getColumnIndex(n1);
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(n1, GridPane.getColumnIndex(n2));
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(n2, temp);
    }


    void imgloader() throws Exception
    {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 0)+1;

        if (rand==1) orgin= ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\untitled\\image1.jpg"));

        bwhite= ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\untitled\\white.jpg"));
    }

    void imagesplitter()
    {
        int val=Difficoulty.diffval;
        int block = 300/val;
        for (int i=0; i<val; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<val; j++)
            {
                BufferedImage tmp= orgin.getSubimage(j*block,i*block,block,block);
                BufferedImage tmpwhite= bwhite.getSubimage(j*block,i*block,block,block);

                done = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(tmp, null );
                iwhite = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(tmpwhite, null );
                arr[i][j]=done;
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert Magic != null : "fx:id=\"Magic\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Grid.fxml'.";

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        gridPane = new GridPane();
        switcher();

        try {
            imgloader();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imagesplitter();
        gridPane.setMinSize(300, 300);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        int val = Difficoulty.diffval;
        for (int i=0; i<val; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<val; j++)
            {
                ImageView iv1=new ImageView(arr[j][i]);
                iv[i][j] = iv1;

                if (i==val-1 && j==val-1)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    gridPane.add(iv[i][j],j,i);
                }

            }
        }


        gridPane.add(special,val-1,val-1);

        Magic.getChildren().addAll(gridPane);

    }

    @FXML private void MainMenu(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{

        Parent newparent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene newscene = new Scene(newparent);

        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(newscene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: A [mre] and a better description of what _currently_ happens versus what _should_ happen would help us better help you. Is the problem just that the handlers aren't being invoked? Are the handlers even added? Are you sure both `initialize(URL,ResourceBundle)` and `initialize()` are invoked (I don't know what happens when both are declared)? Also, please follow [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)—at least when sharing (Java) code in a public space.

Comment: Asside from the problem: I don't recommend getting the `BufferedImage` API involved here: It's not actually necessary. Just create a single instance of `Image` and use the [`ImageView.viewport` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty) to display a part of the `ImageView` in each `ImageView`.

Comment: Inteliji Idea added initialize(URL,ResourceBundle) when i implemented Initializable and Scene Builder added Initialize(). I want the handler to work for each elemet in gridpane. When i created everything in Main (without fxml file, juest created new Scene) that class extended aplication. And in there switcher worked like a charm. Now it does not do anything. Maybe I can iniialize it in fxml file but if I can then how?

Comment: Try tracing how your code is executed. You can do this by adding breakpoints and stepping though the code (i.e. use a debugger) or adding simple print statements at various important places in your code. This will help you narrow down the problem and hopefully discover a solution. Also, try _either_ implementing `Initializable` _or_ using the `initialize()` method. Note the `FXMLLoader` documentation recommends the latter.

Comment: I've moved everything into initialize() method, and now it does not implement Initializable. Still no difference. I know it enters the switcher() but does not print out "sth" when i click the button. The problem might be that in the .fxml file i just have an anchor pane named Magic and I add to this anchor pane GridPane in .java file. There is no trace of this Gridpane in fxml file. Can that be a problem?

Comment: You call `switcher` i.e. the method registering the event handlers to children of the immediately after creating the `GridPane`. At that time no nodes have been added to the `GridPane`. Not a single one of those event handler is registered.